# HTML 5 - GRUNT BUILD : Fatal error: Object has no method 'compact'

Tags: html, gruntjs, npm

I'm trying to build a project with GRUNT. it throws the following error,

```
Running "cuff:dev" (cuff) task
>> Building src/pages/home
Fatal error: Object home.less has no method 'compact'
```

src/pages/home/ -> home.less file,

```
section#home {
}
```

I didn't have any method in home.less. What i did wrong?. I can't understand the meaning of this error.

Answer (score 0):

the info you provided is too less, my guess is `dev` target of `cuff` task has nested tasks probably something related to `home` task taking `less` as target, but grunt is not able to load `less` target. ( probably not defined at all or part of a grunt plugin you forgot to load )

That kind of errors are thrown when you call a target/task but grunt can not find/load it.

use `grunt --help` to load all available commands in your context ( commands from plugins are not shown by this command)